# Angular catch child scope ng-click or property change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a directive attached to a form element and various ng-click events nested within varying child scopes of the form element (e.g. ng-if, ng-repeat).

I would like the form directive to watch and intercept any ng-click, but can't seem to hook into the event or child scope properties in a generic way.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6WdIo5r2FtYWPExBGUru

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form my-form-directive>
      <div ng-controller="SubCtrl">
        <a ng-click="changeName()">click me</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.controller('SubCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'John';

  $scope.changeName = function() {
    $scope.name = 'Peter';
  }
});

app.directive('myFormDirective', 
    function() {
      return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          // would like to watch for either ng-click or $scope.name
          // change and print 'Peter' to the console.log
          // don't assume we know nested location of element with
          // ng-click attached (ok to catch all form ng-click events)
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: What functionality are you aiming to achieve?  As in, why do you want to be able to intercept any ng-click?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things to make this work

Firstly I added jQuery to use the `find` function.

Next we need to move the directive within the `SubCtrl` controller.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="SubCtrl">
    <form my-form-directive name="name">
      <a ng-click="changeName()">click me</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Add a scope parameter `name` to the directive

**HTML**

```
 <form my-form-directive name="name">
```

**JS**

```
 scope: { name: '=' },
```

Finally, within the directive, listen to all the elements with `ng-click` and fire a `click` event when clicked.

**JS**

```
element.find('[ng-click]').on('click', function(){
  console.log($scope.name);
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/7lVWjjT2mssmcBD7uP1Z?p=preview

If you want a pure angular solution, you can add a watch to the the directives `$scope.name`

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch(
  function(){ return $scope.name; }, 
  function(){ console.log($scope.name); }
);
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JG21UvdfBfDoMkCRWKqD?p=preview

Comment: Why `*[ng-click]` instead of `[ng-click]`?

Comment: Thanks, `[ng-click]` will work too and is probably more efficient.  Updated solution

Comment: element.find() only works with selectors if you include jQuery.  Works but not an "angular only" solution.  *[ng-click] catches data-ng-click, etc.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger. Yes you're right. I forgot to mention i added jQuery. Updated